# how to configure alpine to list all remote IMAP folders together?

Tags: command-line, email, configuration, imap, alpine-mail

*This may be tangential to `gmail` usage; I registered a domain with `gandi.net` and want to access that e-mail with `IMAP`.*

While I can edit this directly from `.pinerc` I cannot find this setting through `M S C` to see the configuration file in alpine:

```
# List of directories where saved-message folders may be. First one is
# the default for Saves. Example: Main {host1}mail/[], Desktop mail\[]
# Syntax: optnl-label {optnl-imap-hostname}optnl-directory-path[]
folder-collections=mail/[],
        remote {mail.gandi.net:993/ssl/user=foo@example.com}[]
```

From this setting, `folder-collections`, I can view every folder *except* the "INBOX" which shows as empty in the `remote` list.  There's the apparent inconsistency that the inbox is configured through:

```
# Path of (local or remote) INBOX, e.g. ={mail.somewhere.edu}inbox
# Normal Unix default is the local INBOX (usually /var/spool/mail/$USER).
inbox-path={mail.gandi.net:993/novalidate-cert/ssl/user=foo@example.com}INBOX
```

yet I can only view the inbox and *not* other folders through this configuration.  I cannot easily save messages from the `inbox-path` to a folder in the `remote` collection.

How can I combine both of these settings so that all `gandi.net` folders are in a single list or collection, including the `inbox-path`?  This would make it easier to move messages between folders.